# Adding Items to listbox from an XML File VB (Only works once)

Tags: xml, vb.net, listbox

Here I have tried to add items to a listbox from an XML file. The item only appears the first time I click it and never again after that. I think this is due to the fact that the xml file is being read by the program for only a fraction of a second once the button is clicked and never read again but I am not too sure. 
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnCapp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCapp.Click


    Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\Users\nkarim17\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Company_App\Company_App\bin\Debug\MyName.xml")

    ListBox1.Items.Add("Cappuccino")

    If (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\nkarim17\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Company_App\Company_App\bin\Debug\MyName.xml")) Then

        While (document.Read())

            Dim type = document.NodeType

            If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                If (document.Name = "Cap") Then

                    ListBox2.Items.Add(document.ReadInnerXml.ToString())

                End If

            End If

        End While

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("The File was not found")

    End If


End Sub
```

And here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<Data>
  <Person>
    <Cap>3</Cap>
  </Person>
</Data>
```

Let me know if there is any way to fix this. Thanks :)

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Problem solved. It was merely a stupid mistake. I had the

 Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\Users\nkarim17\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Company_App\Company_App\bin\Debug\MyName.xml")

in the wrong place. Thanks for your help anyway